# How to determine the register with the greatest content

Tags: max, verilog

what is the best way to figure out which register contains the largest number?

```
reg [7:0] A;
reg [7:0] B;
reg [7:0] C;
reg [7:0] D;

reg [7:0] M;

always @(posedge CLK) begin
    M <= max(A,B,C,D);
end
```

Comment: how do you want to interpret the data? As signed? As unsigned? As Grey code? As BCD? It's just bits in there.

Comment: Its just the BCD Input of a 4-channel ADC. I would like to figure out which channel has the largest value on each clock cycle.

Comment: So it's just two decimal digits numbers. Can you write a comparator for them?

Comment: Could you show me an example with 4 inputs?
If I had just 2 inputs it would be simple `if(A > B) M <= A; else M <= B`

Comment: Hint: `max(A,B,C,D)=max(max(A,B), max(C,D) )`

Answer (score 0):

```
always @(posedge CLK)
begin

if(A > B && A > C && A > D)
begin
M <= A;
end
else if(B > A && B > C && B > D)
begin
M <= B;
end
else if(C > A && C > B && C > D)
begin
M <= C;
end
else if(D > A && D > B && D > C)
begin
M <= D;
end
//else
// there are two or more regs have the same value
end
```

Comment: I think this could be simplified by
`if(A >= B && A >= C && A >= D) M <= A; else if(B >= C && B >= D) M <= B; else if(C >= D) M <= C; else M <= D;`
because in the `else if` cases you can be shure the one before didn't match.

Comment: You are right bro :) ... just a question if there are two values are equal what do you want M to be?